# Raspberry Pi NoIR V2.1 blurry image

Tags: raspicam

I have an Raspberry Pi 1 and a NoIR V2.1. I also bought an IF lamp and with an slow enough shutter_speed the brightness gets good enough, but the image is really blurry.

I created an image with the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep
from fractions import Fraction

camera = PiCamera(resolution=(1280, 720), framerate=Fraction(1, 6))
camera.shutter_speed = 60250
camera.iso = 400

camera.exposure_mode = 'auto'

camera.capture('pics/test.jpg')
```

I also tried to play with the camera.sharpness, but this seems to have little to no effect to the sharpness (Created 200 pics in an loop with every sharpness setting)

Here's a picture of the cam:

[image]

Is this normal, or is there anything else I have to do to get an clear picture?

Comment: Have you removed the plastic covering the lens?

Comment: Yes I removed that

Comment: The first batch of V2 modules produced had their focal point set nearer than infinity (lots of info in [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=971091#p971091)). First I'd confirm that you still get blur with a short exposure (as Julian suggests with a long exposure even minimal jitter will result in a blurry image). If you still get blur, and you don't mind a slightly risky procedure you can [adjust the focus manually](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=971545#p971545).

Comment: Thanks, I got my money back. As I was allowed to keep the camera, I will try to adjust the focus manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to hace the cam totally stable, so there will be absolutely no movement of the cam during taking pictures, since even very small movements or vibrations of the cam will cause blurr in a long exposure picture.

If the blurr will still be present, I assume you got a faulty camera and suggest you to contact the dealer for a replacement. Faulty cameras are a known [issue](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=45122)